# Entity framework exclude fields from insert

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Model class:

```
public class position
{
    public string positioncode { get; set; }
    public string english { get; set; }
    public string chinese { get; set; }
    public string big5 { get; set; }
    public string jd { get; set; }
    public string japanese { get; set; }
    public int orgid { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int positionid { get; set; }
}
```

DBContext:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TestWebAPI1.Models.position> positions { get; set; }
```

and controller post method, where I have to insert record into database based on incoming JSON html:

```
    // POST api/position
    [ResponseType(typeof(position))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Postposition(position theposition)
    {
        db.positions.Add(theposition);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

My question is: whether is it possible to generate insert statement based on the fields, received in JSON and avoid NULLS in the fields, which were omitted in JSON, like:

```
insert into position (positionid, positioncode ) values (2, "TEMP");
```

instead of insert statement with all fields listed, which is by default entity framework behavior.

Comment: You can, but i'll have to define another context for this. And also, why do you need this? This trick won't level-up your performance and in terms of database you'll still have nulls. You have so defaults or triggers in your table?

Comment: Thank you Alex. I have table with 100+ columns, of course INSERT statement will be full of NULLS in my case when only few fields needed to be inserted actually. I tried to separate initial insert into two transactions: simple insert + update:  1) db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand (insert into ....) and then 2) [  db.positions.Attach(theposition); .....  entry.Property(prop.Name).IsModified = true; await db.SaveChangesAsync(); ] It works, UPDATE is sent only with few needed fields, but two statements have to be sent to the database: INSERT + UPDATE.

Comment: Now my question is whether is it possible to tell Entity Framework which fields to generate in insert statement like with Update: IsModified = true / false.  Then I will be able to make only one transaction.

Comment: And definitely I want to avoid using ExecuteSqlCommand("insert into position (positionid) values(" + theposition.positionid +
                                                  ")");, wish to generate insert SQL statement by Entity Framework alone. Let it be a new database context - does not matter.

Comment: I think you get it wrong from performance meaning.Your overhead on using EF will totally ruin all your optimization with nulls in insert statements.I performed a simple test:created a table with 40 columns and made 2 inserts:one was with huge amount of nulls(for 38 columns) and another was 'insert into #Test(Id) Values(1)'.Yep,the second worked a little faster(i inserted 100000 rows, first took 2 secs,second- 1.5 sec).But EF definitely cannot insert even 1000 rows per second. If you need performance, you need to deal with EF batching, transactions and so on, but not with inserts statement size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rather straight-forward solution you can use.

Define a different context like this:

```
public class PositionsContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Position> Type { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //define ignores here
        modelBuilder.Entity<Position>().Ignore(t => t.big5);
    }
}
```

And define ignores as you need em. But first, read my answer to bottom, i think you walk in wrong direction trying to achieve performance here. 
Your overhead on using EF will totally ruin all your optimization with nulls in insert statements.I performed a simple test:created a table with 40 columns and made 2 inserts:one was with huge amount of nulls(for 38 columns) and another was 'insert into #Test(Id) Values(1)'.Yep,the second worked a little faster(i inserted 100000 rows, first took 2 secs,second- 1.5 sec).But EF definitely cannot insert even 1000 rows per second. If you need performance, you need to deal with EF batching, transactions and so on, but not with inserts statement size